# Python/Keras - How to access each epoch prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras to predict a time series. As standard I'm using 20 epochs.
I want to check if my model is learning well, by predicting for each one of the 20 epochs.

By using `model.predict()` I'm getting only one prediction among all epochs (not sure how Keras selects it). I want all predictions, or at least the 10 best.

Would anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think there is a bit of a confusion here.

An epoch is only used while training the neural network, so when training stops (in this case, after the 20th epoch), then the weights correspond to the ones computed on the last epoch.

Keras prints current loss values on the validation set during training after each epoch. If the weights after each epoch are not saved, then they are lost.  You can save weights for each epoch with the [ModelCheckpoint](http://keras.io/callbacks/) callback, and then load them back with *load_weights* on your model.

You can compute your predictions after each training epoch by implementing an appropriate callback by subclassing [Callback](http://keras.io/callbacks/) and calling predict on the model inside the *on_epoch_end* function.

Then to use it, you instantiate your callback, make a list and use it as keyword argument callbacks to *model.fit*.

Comment: Hello Matias! If you could have a look on this one it would be highly appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895627/python-keras-creating-a-callback-with-one-prediction-for-each-epoch

Answer (score 11):

The following code will do the desired job:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

# define your custom callback for prediction
class PredictionCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):    
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    y_pred = self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])
    print('prediction: {} at epoch: {}'.format(y_pred, epoch))

# ...

# register the callback before training starts
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=25, 
          validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), 
          callbacks=[PredictionCallback()])
```

Comment: this seems causing memory leak

Comment: it does not work in TF 2.x:
AttributeError: 'PredictionCallback' object has no attribute 'validation_data'

Comment: This callback structure will call predict again, even though keras has already made predictions during the epoch, doubling the prediction workload. Is it not possible to access the predictions we know keras has already made during the epoch?

Answer (score 4):

**In case you want to make predictions on the test data, after every epoch while the training is going-on you can try this**

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, x_test, y_test):
        self.model = model
        self.x_test = x_test
        self.y_test = y_test

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.x_test, self.y_test)
        print('y predicted: ', y_pred)
```

You need mention the callback during model.fit

```
model.sequence()
# your model architecture
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[CustomCallback(model, x_test, y_test)])
```

Similar to `on_epoch_end` there are many other methods provided by keras

```
on_train_begin, on_train_end, on_epoch_begin, on_epoch_end, on_test_begin,
on_test_end, on_predict_begin, on_predict_end, on_train_batch_begin, on_train_batch_end,
on_test_batch_begin, on_test_batch_end, on_predict_batch_begin,on_predict_batch_end
```

Comment: Similar to the other answer above, this callback structure will call predict again, even though keras has already made predictions during the epoch, doubling the prediction workload. Is it not possible to access the predictions we know keras has already made during the epoch?