# Python/Keras - Creating a callback with one prediction for each epoch

Tags: python, subclassing, keras

I'm using Keras to predict a time series. As standard I'm using 20 epochs. I want to know what did my neural network predict for each one of the 20 epochs.

By using model.predict I'm getting only one prediction among all epochs (not sure how Keras select it). I want all predictions, or at least the 10 best.

According to a previous answer I got, I should compute the predictions after each training epoch by implementing an appropriate callback by subclassing `Callback()` and calling predict on the model inside the `on_epoch_end` function.

Well, the theory seems in shape but I'm in trouble to code that. Would anyone be able to give a code example on that?

Not sure how to implement the `Callback()` subclassing and neither how to mix that with the `model.predict` inside an `on_epoch_end`  function.

Your help will be highly appreciated :)

---

**EDIT**

Well, I evolved a little bit.
Found out how to create the subclass and how to link it to the model.predict.
However, I'm burning my brain on how to create a list with all the predictions. Below is my current code:

```
#Creating a Callback subclass that stores each epoch prediction
class prediction_history(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.predhis=(model.predict(predictor_train))

#Calling the subclass
predictions=prediction_history()

#Executing the model.fit of the neural network
model.fit(X=predictor_train, y=target_train, nb_epoch=2, batch_size=batch,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[predictions]) 

#Printing the prediction history
print predictions.predhis
```

However, all I'm getting with that is a list of predictions of the last epoch (same effect as printing model.predict(predictor_train)).

The question now is: How do I adapt my code so it adds to `predhis`  the predictions of each one of the epochs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are overwriting the prediction for each epoch, that is why it doesn't work. I would do it like this:

```
class prediction_history(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.predhis = []
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.predhis.append(model.predict(predictor_train))
```

This way self.predhis is now a list and each prediction is appended to the list at the end of each epoch.

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks a lot for all the help Matias.

Comment: I have tried using the code snippet, but in the "def on_batch_end()" part of the Callback. But when doing this, `model.predict(predictor_train)` evaluates the model on the entire training set instead of just the current batch. Is there a way to changes this?

Comment: @Lemon There is no "current batch" at the end of the epoch, you just have to change predictor_train to whatever data you want to use for evaluation.

Comment: For more detail see the official Keras documentation on callbacks, https://keras.io/callbacks/