# How to check the predicted output during fitting of the model in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am new in Keras and I learned fitting and evaluating the model. 
After evaluating  the model one can see the actual predictions made by model.

I am wondering Is it also possible to see the predictions during fitting in Keras? Till now I cant find any code doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Keras - How to access each epoch prediction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864774/python-keras-how-to-access-each-epoch-prediction)

Answer (score 2):

Since this question doesn't specify "epochs", and since using callbacks may represent extra computation, I don't think it's exactly a duplication.

With tensorflow, you can use a custom training loop with eager execution turned on. A simple tutorial for creating a custom training loop: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough

Basically you will:

```
#transform your data in to a Dataset:
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (x_train, y_train)).shuffle(some_buffer).batch(batchSize) 
     #the above is buggy in some versions regarding shuffling, you may need to shuffle
     #again between each epoch    


#create an optimizer    
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

#create an epoch loop:
for e in range(epochs):

    #create a batch loop
    for i, (x, y_true) in enumerate(dataset):

        #create a tape to record actions
        with  tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            #take the model's predictions
            y_pred = model(x)

            #calculate loss
            loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        #calculate gradients
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)

        #apply gradients
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights)
```

You can use the `y_pred` var for doing anything, including getting its `numpy_pred = y_pred.numpy()` value.

The tutorial gives some more details about metrics and validation loop.

Comment: so can i assume Keras doesn't provide any function to get the predicted data during training? one has to go deep into tensorflow to get the predicted data?

Comment: Not that I know. But I never found anything besides callbacks as in the suggested comment. But callbacks will need to run the prediction again.