# To create a custom metrics for regression according to the rule book of Keras' documentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics

I found two main sources about it.

1. [A tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/), not done according to the rule book (I prefer avoid)
2. [Keras' documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_metrics) (what I prefer to avoid surprises)

I prefer to follow Keras' documentation to avoid memory leak as it's the case for some people who [try custom approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59231724/10314460) with Keras. 
But what Keras' is showing in the documentation is about classification. This is not my case.
So I tried to look at the source code of Keras. Precisely in the file: `/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/metrics.py`. It does not help me at all because most of metrics (some exception are classification metrics) are all done with a wrapper as the following code:

````
@keras_export('keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError')
class MeanSquaredError(MeanMetricWrapper):
    """Computes the mean squared error between `y_true` and `y_pred`.

    For example, if `y_true` is [0., 0., 1., 1.], and `y_pred` is [1., 1., 1., 0.]
    the mean squared error is 3/4 (0.75).

    Usage:

    ```python
    m = tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()
    m.update_state([0., 0., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1., 0.])
    print('Final result: ', m.result().numpy())  # Final result: 0.75
    ```

    Usage with tf.keras API:

    ```python
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile('sgd', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])
    ```
    """

    def __init__(self, name='mean_squared_error', dtype=None):
        super(MeanSquaredError, self).__init__(
            mean_squared_error, name, dtype=dtype)
````

As you can see there's only the constructor method, no good inspiration available for the `udpate_state` method that I need. 
Where can I find it ?

---

python 3.7.7
tensorflow 2.1.0
keras-applications 1.0.8
keras-preprocessing 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loss function as a metric, so you can extend `keras.losses.Loss` instead. You only need to override `call` as shown in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss)

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MeanSquaredError(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```